# How to get Outlook attachment to a server from a mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Every day we receive an email with an Excel attachment in our group mailbox.  I created a rule that executes a VBScript to save the attachment to a server as a .csv file.

This works well in my personal Outlook as a client rule. But the Outlook rule doesn't work for the group mailbox. Nobody has this group mailbox opened as the primary mailbox.

Is there a way to either get the VBScript to run against the group mailbox or an alterative method to get the attached spreadsheet saved to a server as a .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Microsoft Exchange (which I'm guessing is true), you can write a PowerShell script to run on the server on a schedule to poll the mailbox for new attachments and save them.

Comment: Thanks, Randolph.  I am primarily a mainframe devloper so knw nothing about PowerShell.  Maybe now is a good time to learn.